# Laravel Database Transactions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpunit

I have a service class that makes use of DB transactions.

eg.

```php
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    ...
    DB::commit()
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    ...
    DB::rollBack();
}
```

When I try to test this service and I use the `RefreshDatabase` trait, it ends up throwing an error like `"There is no active transaction"`.

Has anyone been able to test a service class that uses DB transactions?

Comment: `RefreshDatabase` uses transactions itself, so that might be the problem ... https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test ... "The `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase` trait does not migrate your database if your schema is up to date. Instead, it will only execute the test within a database transaction."

Comment: Yes that's the problem. There is an answer in the duplicate that shows you how to write your own DB connection layer to test the environment and disable transactions in case it's a testing environment. Seems like the best workaround until this is fixed in Laravel.